# É possível fazer um swipe para abrir o aplicativo?

Tags: android, ios, apache-cordova

Gostaria de saber se é possível criar um evento em uma aplicação que realize essa função, e se existe algum plugin.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Vou ser bem direto: sim, é. Dê olhada no aplicativo Google Now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sobre iOs:

Na tela inicial do iOs isso é impossível, agora dentro de uma aplicação iOS sua dá para fazer esse slide puxando uma foto, por exemplo, e quando finalizar a animação abre uma aplicação externa ( mas ainda sim terá a animação do outro app vindo da direita ).

Sobre ambos ( iOS e Android ):

O usuário espera que quando puxa o canto superior da tela venha uma tela com notificações e ou ajustes. Esse tipo de feature que você ta propondo ( mesmo se possível ) seria bem invasiva e não recomendável e estaria fora das guidelines tanto da Google quanto da Apple.